# Not able to locate "datagen" folder and BUILD file even if it exist

Tags: bazel

I am trying to run a bazel project from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/healthcare/tree/master/fhir/immunizations_demo.

Can you please help me out with the folder name from where one need to execute following command ? Looks like datagen and BUILD file both exists although still bazel is complaining it could not find it

```
bazel run //datagen:data_gen -- --num=1 --output_path=demo_data.ndjson
```

I tried running it on **"healthcare/fhir/immunizations_demo"** folder but it failed with below error

```
INFO: Invocation ID: 26092ad2-2ae0-49c9-ac2c-4988bf053007
ERROR: Skipping '//datagen:data_gen': no such package 'datagen': BUILD file not found on package path
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package 'datagen': BUILD file not found on package path
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.070s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bazel run //fhir/immunizations_demo/datagen:data_gen -- --num=1 --output_path=demo_data.ndjson
```

`//` refers to the directory where the `WORKSPACE` file is, so the full target label is `//fhir/immunizations_demo/datagen:data_gen`.